# PHP change Date & Time Raspberry Pi using PHP

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm using `Raspberry Pi 3`.

I know when I want to change date time for that `Raspberry Pi 3` is:

```
sudo date -s "11/20/2017 11:00"
```

And Now I want it can be change using PHP. Is it possible? How to do it?

Tried this code, but not working:

```
<?php 
$sys_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2015-12-02"));
$sys_time ="08:00:00";
$sys_datetime = $sys_date." ".$sys_time;
$sys_datetime =strtotime($sys_datetime);
$date = gmdate('D M d H:i:s e Y', $sys_datetime);
shell_exec("sudo date -s \"$date\"");
?>
```

Comment: Your web-server user - I don't know what that is on your configuration, `apache`, `www`, etc. -  needs to be in the `/etc/sudoers` file in order to be able to execute the `sudo` command. Is it?

Comment: Hi... I'm using lighttpd. Then what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sys_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2015-12-02"));
$sys_time ="08:00:00";
$sys_datetime = $sys_date." ".$sys_time;
$sys_datetime =strtotime($sys_datetime);
echo $date = gmdate('m/d/y h:i', $sys_datetime); // <-- made changes here
```

Output:

```
12/02/15 08:00
```

Comment: I would like to change `Raspberry Pi 3` Date & Time, not echoing